# Problems with Cubic Hermite polynomial in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I am having trouble with this code for a piecewise cubic Hermite polynomial.  In my assignment we are not allowed to use `pchip`. We are supposed to write a function which takes as it's input arguments an integer n and a 3 by n matrix which contains the x values, the values of a function evaluated at each x, and the values of the derivative evaluated at each x; in the first, second and third rows of the matrix respectively.

With this information we are supposed to calculate the coefficients for each Hermite polynomial on each subinterval of the interval given by the first row of the input matrix, then piece it altogether using `mkpp`.

Unfortunately, my code produces a very poor interpolating polynomial and I am having trouble figuring out why.  For example for the function `x^2` we have for instance `n = 4` and `M = [0,1,2,3; 0,1,4,9; 0,1,4,6]` and when plugged into my function produces the following graph

[image]

I would really appreciate help with this, it's driving me nuts.

Here is my code:

```
function [ HP ] = HermiteInter( n,M )
%HermiteInter 
%  This function constructs a peicewise cubic Hermite polynomial.
%  The input areguments are an integer n and M a 3 by n matrix, whose
%  first row contains the values of x which a given function will be
%  evaluated at. The second row contains the values of a function
%  evaluated at those
%  points and the third row contains the value of the derivative of
%  the function evaluated at those points.
%  Divided differences using these values are found by calling the
%  function HermiteDD. These divided differences are then passed into the
%  function mkpp to create the peicewise polynomial.

X = M(1,:);
Y = M(2,:);
Z = M(3,:);

Q = zeros(n-1,4);

for i = 1 : n-1
 Q(i,:) = HermiteDD([X(i),X(i),X(i+1),X(i+1)],[Y(i),Y(i+1)],[Z(i),Z(i+1)]);
end
HP = mkpp(X,Q);
end

function [ HDD ] = HermiteDD(X,Y,Z)
%HermiteDD 
%   This function creates a table of divided differences for
%   Hermite polynomials.  The input arguments are X, the values at 
%   which a function was evaluated at, Y the values of the function at
%   these points and Z the values of the derivative of the function at 
%   these points.

DD = zeros(4, 4);
DD(1, 1) = Y(1);
DD(2, 1) = Y(1);
DD(3, 1) = Y(2);
DD(4, 1) = Y(2);
DD(1, 2) = Z(1);
DD(2, 2) = (Y(1)-Y(2))/(X(1)-X(3));
DD(3, 2) = Z(2);
for j = 3 : 4
    for i = 1 : (4 - j+1)
        DD(i,j) = (DD(i + 1, j - 1) - DD(i, j - 1)) / (X(i + j-1) - X(i));
    end
end
HDD = DD(1,:);


end
```